# msgraph-sdk-go can't create more than two extensions on a user

Tags: azure, go, microsoft-graph-api

When I try to create an schema extension on a user like this

```
schemaExtension := graphmodels.NewSchemaExtension()
additionalData := map[string]interface{}{
    "extensionName": "dean.ext.test.1",
    "theme":         "dark",
    "color":         "purple",
    "lang":          "English",
}
schemaExtension.SetAdditionalData(additionalData)

if result, err := client.UsersById(userId).Extensions().Post(context.Background(), schemaExtension, nil); err != nil {
```

I get this error:

```
Error: error status code received from the API
    code: BadRequest
    msg: Maximum number of extensions values supported per application is 2.
```

But I have not created any schema extensions on this user.  I created two open extensions, but I should be able to create additional schema extensions.

Why does the error message say that extensions are per application?  The code above is trying to create an extension on a particular user, not an application.

I want to remove the extensions on this user, but there is nothing I can find in the portal that shows extensions for a user.  Where can I find the extensions on a user in the portal?

The portal does show user attributes which seem to apply to all users.  Are user attributes related to extensions?  How can I access these user attributes using the msgraph-sdk-go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The msgraph-sdk-go is currently at v 0.55 and is a non-production preview.
After discussing this with some colleagues we've decided to drop the MS Graph SDK and use the v 1.0 Graph REST endpoints directly.  They've had success with that approach and have found that the SDK doesn't help very much.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

When I ran below request to create extension via [***Graph Explorer***](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), I got **same error** as you like below:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userID>/extensions

{
    "extensionName": "dean.ext.test.1",
    "theme": "dark",
    "color": "purple",
    "lang": "English"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Note that, you can create only **2** open extensions for any directory
> resource like user, group, device etc... To **confirm** that, you can
> check this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview?tabs=http#choose-an-extension-type-for-your-application) on limits.

The error usually occurs if you already have **2** open extensions existing in your directory. You can make use of below **MS Graph query** to list open extensions on a user.

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userID>/extensions
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can **get** the same results using `msgraph-sdk-go` with below code:

```golang
graphClient := msgraphsdk.NewGraphServiceClient(requestAdapter)

result, err := graphClient.UsersById("user-id").Extensions().Get(context.Background(), nil)
```

To **delete** extension from user, you can use below query by including extension name like this:

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userID>/extensions/<extension_name>
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can **delete** open extension from user using `msgraph-sdk-go` with below code:

```golang
graphClient := msgraphsdk.NewGraphServiceClient(requestAdapter)
  
graphClient.UsersById("user-id").ExtensionsById("extension-id").Delete(context.Background(), nil)
```

When I ran the query to list open extensions now, I got only **1** extension in response as other one is deleted successfully like below:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userID>/extensions
```

**Response:**
[image]

The code you are currently using to create **schema extensions** is creating `open extensions`.

To **create** schema extension using `msgraph-sdk-go`, once cross-check your code with below sample code:

```golang
graphClient := msgraphsdk.NewGraphServiceClient(requestAdapter)

requestBody := graphmodels.NewSchemaExtension()
id := "domainName_schemaName"
requestBody.SetId(&id) 
description := "My schema extension"
requestBody.SetDescription(&description) 
targetTypes := []string {
    "User",

}
requestBody.SetTargetTypes(targetTypes)


extensionSchemaProperty := graphmodels.NewExtensionSchemaProperty()
name := "theme"
extensionSchemaProperty.SetName(&name) 
type := "String"
extensionSchemaProperty.SetType(&type) 
extensionSchemaProperty1 := graphmodels.NewExtensionSchemaProperty()
name := "color"
extensionSchemaProperty1.SetName(&name) 
type := "String"
extensionSchemaProperty1.SetType(&type) 
extensionSchemaProperty2 := graphmodels.NewExtensionSchemaProperty()
name := "lang"
extensionSchemaProperty2.SetName(&name) 
type := "String"
extensionSchemaProperty2.SetType(&type) 

properties := []graphmodels.ExtensionSchemaPropertyable {
    extensionSchemaProperty,
    extensionSchemaProperty1,
    extensionSchemaProperty2,

}
requestBody.SetProperties(properties)

result, err := graphClient.SchemaExtensions().Post(context.Background(), requestBody, nil)
```

**Reference:** [Create schemaExtension - Microsoft Graph v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/schemaextension-post-schemaextensions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=go#example-1-creating-a-schema-extension-using-a-verified-domain)

**UPDATE:**

As mentioned in your answer, `THE GO SDK IS IN PREVIEW. IT IS FOR NON-PRODUCTION USE ONLY`. So, it's better to stick with REST API calls, for now, to manage resources via MS Graph.

Comment: Why does the code `schemaExtension := graphmodels.NewSchemaExtension()` create an open extension?  You show the same in your example above.

Comment: How do you create the requestAdapter shown in your code?  The MS graph docs don't show how to create requestAdapter either.

Comment: Check this line in your code `result, err := client.UsersById(userId).Extensions().Post(context.Background(), schemaExtension, nil); err != nil`.

Comment: It should be `result, err := graphClient.SchemaExtensions().Post(context.Background(), requestBody, nil)`

Comment: If you post request to only `Extensions()`, it will create open extensions. Make sure to post request to `SchemaExtensions()` to create schema extensions.

Comment: Your example doesn't create an extension on a user.  I need to create an extension for a user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252162/discussion-between-sridevi-and-dean-schulze).